# Output a single property and its value from the object

Tags: angularjs

I have a function, which adds/removes a new input field on click. Each field has its own ng-model kid.age. And the function calculate the premium, which depends on the age.
The result of the function is an array of objects like this:

```
[{"id":"kid1","age":2,"btaccident":0.79,"btdisability":0.13,"btdeath":0.18, "premium": 5},{"id":"kid2","age":3,"btaccident":0.79,"btdisability":0.13,"btdeath":0.18, "premium": 5}]
```

The number of objects depends on how many times the add button will be clicked.

How can I output the only property "premium" with its value of each object in the VIEW, as I don't know the final number of objects?

Comment: [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate the array of results and display only the premium field, that is accomplished by the usage of `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <span ng-bind="item.premium"></span>
</div>
```